# GCD as integral operator

Tags: integration, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Kind of weird question, but is there something like an integral operator which returns $1$ if $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ and $0$ otherwise, meaning
$$
\int_{D} K(a, b, t) \, {\rm d}t = \begin{cases} 1 \qquad \gcd(a, b) = 1 \\ 0 \qquad {\rm else} \end{cases} \, .
$$
where $D$ is some appropriate integration domain and $K$ the kernel.
Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've forgotten about the [Kronecker delta](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerDelta.html). I love Lethe, mwahahahahha! Then $$\delta_1^{\gcd(a, b)} = 1$$ if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, and $$\delta_1^{\gcd(a, b)} = 0$$ otherwise.

Comment: well... were is the integral ;)
PS: let me guess...now you tell me $$\int_0^1 e^{i2\pi t (\gcd(a,b)-1)} \, {\rm d} t \, ?$$

Comment: now I tell you to play around with Mathematica or Maple or something like that

Comment: why?to do what?

Comment: To see what different (pun intended, shoot me) integrals you can come up with using the Kronecker delta.

Comment: Hey, this is somewhat 2 years old, but I just wanted to say that with integral operator I meant an operator that does not depend on using the gcd function.